# Can I add card values to power intensity in SAGA Marvel system?

Tags: marvel-saga

Some powers like plasticity state that one can "raise his or her streight to the power's intensity".

I would like to know if, when I use this stunt, I can add card value to it in order to raise it.

Comment: Should that quote say something like "her strength" or was that not a typo at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you mean as part of a normal action. This essentially means that your strength becomes the level of the power for the purpose of the action.So if you have a character who is strength 4 but a plasticity of 12 has an effective strength of 12. But otherwise, it functions normally, so that if you are attempting a strength action, you play cards as normal but with a effective strength of 12.  it's still stat+cards+extra cards but at a higher level. You aren't play a card to use the power, the power is kind of always affecting you and you're playing actions at that higher level.

If you wanted to be able to increase your standard strength above the  plasticity rank - buy more points in the rank or come up with a unique stunt (colossus has something similar in that his power rank and effective strength don't match up).